# :after class not working with img tag

Tags: css

i want to add background color overlay effects when hovering on the image.But i have tried few times with css pseudo-class`:after`, it is just not working, the code as:

```
<div class="test">
  <img src="assets/img/slide1.jpeg" class="overlay" alt="">
   <!-- my image tag -->
</div>
```

the css:

```
  .test{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.overlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:after{
  content: "test";
  position: absolute;
  font-size:3em;
}
```

the `.overlay:after`content is not showing up, but it is working when i am using `:after` class on the `<p>`or `<span>`tag, and i was intend to adding overlay color effects on my `<img>`tag as:

```
/*adding background color on the image tag using :after*/
.overlay:after{
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

So my questions are:
1. Why the pseudo class `:after` not working on the img tag but working with the text tag such as `<p>`or`<h1>`?
2. Is there anything wrong with my code on adding red bg color using `:after`?

Comment: :after only works on container elements which can contain text content (because it works by attaching content after the initial content), so as you've discovered, unfortunately it won't work on img, you need to use a wrapper element and attach it to that.

Answer (score 4):

*Pseudo-elements* can only be declared on **containing elements**; *elements that can contain other elements*, e.g: `<p>`, `<span>`, `<h1>`, etc.

Since `<img>` is a **self-closing void tag** (also known as *empty elements*) that *cannot contain other elements*, *pseudo-elements*, like `:after` or `:before` cannot be used.

[Empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) - a list of *empty elements*

> An empty element is an element from HTML, SVG, or MathML that cannot
>   have any child nodes (i.e., nested elements or text nodes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `img` in a block element to use `:after` or psuedo elements.

```css
.overlay{
  position:relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.overlay img{
  width: 100%;
}

/*adding background color on the image tag using :after*/

.overlay:hover:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="hola">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `:after` pseudo element is inserted inside the element to which it is applied, as its last child. Because it is not possible for an `img` tag to have children, `:after` will have no effect on it.

Instead, you can apply the overlay to its parent element:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.wrap img {
    display: block;
}
.wrap:hover:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```